# Make render window be "Always on Top"?

Tags: python, macos, vtk

I have some python code running a very basic VTK visualization on both Ubuntu and OSX. On Ubuntu everything works perfectly, but on OSX I get the annoying issue that when the rendering window is initialized, it's initialized behind my editor.

With frameworks like PyQt it is straightforward to just make it stay on top, but this is a wrapper over C++, so things seem more complex.

I found this link, starting at line 724, that seems to point out what setting I need to change

https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Rendering/OpenGL/vtkCocoaRenderWindow.mm

```
  // This will hide the menu and the dock
  [theWindow setLevel:NSMainMenuWindowLevel+1];
  // This will show the menu and the dock
  //[theWindow setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel];
```

However it seems impossible to access this `SetLevel` method from within my Python script.

How can I ensure my rendering windows are always floating on top of everything else on OSX?

Comment: You can use ctypes, i did from js-ctypes have you tried with python ctypes?